# libssh2 unable to exchange encryption keys

Tags: php, sftp, libssh2

I'm trying to connect to a SFTP server with the following command:

```
<?php
ssh2_connect("my-host.com", 443, array("client_to_server" => array("mac" => "hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,umac-64@openssh.com")));
```

But I get the following error message:

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace: 
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0 
PHP   2. ssh2_connect() Command line code:1 
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to my-host.com in Command line code on line 1 
PHP Stack trace: 
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0 
PHP   2. ssh2_connect() Command line code:1
```

And when I check the logs of my SFTP server, I can see:

```
2016-08-17 15:32:43,104 mod_sftp/0.9.9[10701]: no shared client-to-server MAC algorithm found (client sent 'hmcom', server sent 'hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,umac-64@openssh.com')
```

Could you help me?
Ben

Comment: It may be that your `libssh2` build does not support those MAC algorithms.  Is it possible to change the `mod_sftp` configuration to allow a wider range of MAC algorithms?